# R plot, change scale of values for plot axis

Tags: r, plot

I am doing a plot with R, the code for stacked bar and axis 2 are simple, here is the code for line and axis 4:

[image]

```
lines(y, 
    theLineValues,     
    type    = "o", 
    pch     = 20,
    lwd     = 2, 
    cex     = 1.2, 
    lty     = 1, 
    col     ="forestgreen")

axis(4, 
    at      = getYaxis(0,1,0.01, 3),    # function to get 3 values for axis
    labels  = getYaxis(0,1,0.01, 3),
    col.axis= "forestgreen", 
    las     = 1,
    cex.axis= 0.7,
    col     = "forestgreen",
    line    = 0)
```

then I found the min and max value: 0.46, 0.68 , and want to use them as axis, so the changing of line can be seen more obviously(the red line).

```
labels  = getYaxis(min(theLineValues),max(theLineValues),0.01,3),
```

[image]

How would I scale the 'theLineValues' to do this?

Thanks.

======================================================================
Update 1: the code for 'y':

```
y <- barplot(
    combinedvalues,     # it's list of 3-combined values.
    col     = c("slategray1","darkseagreen1","moccasin"),
    beside  = FALSE,
    border = "grey80",
    las     = 1,
    cex.axis= 1.0,
    ann     = FALSE,
    ylim    = c(0,1),
    yaxt    = "n")
```

======================================================================
Update 2: the combined values:

these values are in .csv file, and use the following to get the 'combinedvalues' and pass it to 'y':

```
rbind(csv$frame0,csv$frame1,csv$frame2)
# frame0+frame1+frame2 shoud be 1, theLineValues were calculated by some formulas.
```

the csv file:

```
frame0          frame1          frame2          theLineValues
------------------------------------------------------------
0.4460203874    0.2271394791    0.3268401336    0.4674583872
0.4473756948    0.2084173711    0.3442069341    0.4796977238
0.5296042291    0.1570493286    0.3133464423    0.570317484
0.5255498752    0.1234146373    0.3510354875    0.6095475721
0.5405768621    0.119299957     0.3401231808    0.6251561825
0.5657840709    0.0916650587    0.3425508703    0.6896446583
0.4826617968    0.0877739789    0.4295642243    0.6610089801
0.3588171226    0.122977733     0.5182051444    0.606129318
0.2608499204    0.1705417922    0.5686082874    0.595971676
0.2111782825    0.2040231107    0.5847986067    0.6057364576
0.1731616573    0.240909341     0.5859290016    0.6153720603
```

Thanks.

======================================================================
Update 3: the final plot:

[image]

Comment: if it is baseplot try ylim=c(min(theLineValues), max(theLineValues))

Comment: btw. Could you give the values of y ?

Comment: y (the stacked barplot) needs yllime = c(0,1)

Comment: do you have the values of combinedvalues?

Comment: I provided a solution below in the answer box, hope it helps you!

Comment: hi Ruthger, thanks very much for your helps. Finally, I did the plot (update 3). I guess, the line cannot be aligned to each bars (as the first picture showed) by using this method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Frames.txt is based on the three frame columns.

**Data**

```
frames <- read.table("/your-path/frames.txt",header=T,na.string="NA")

theLineValues<-c(0.4674583872, 0.4796977238, 0.570317484, 0.6095475721, 0.6251561825, 0.6896446583, 0.6610089801, 0.606129318, 0.595971676, 0.6057364576, 0.6153720603)
```

**Plot**

```
barplot(t(frames), , col = c("slategray1","darkseagreen1","moccasin"))
axis(2, ylim=c(0,1))
mtext("barplot values", side=2, line=2)
box()

par(new=TRUE)
plot(theLineValues, type = "l", pch = 20, xlab="", ylab="", col = "forestgreen", lwd=2, ylim=c(min(theLineValues), max(theLineValues)), axes=FALSE)
axis(4, ylim=c(min(theLineValues), max(theLineValues)))
mtext("lineValues", side=4, line=0.2)
box()
```

[image]